# OSCommerce - Paypal Express - Godaddy : Session ID reassigned

Tags: paypal, oscommerce, ccavenue

Am shared hosted on Godaddy and have SSL installed and configured.

My cart is OSCommerce 2.3.4.

I have enabled Paypal Express checkout and CCavenue payment gateways.

> Problem is After adding products to the cart and checking out, am able to seamlessly go to the payment gateway provider website for making the payment.

After making payment and coming back to merchant website, am getting a new session ID compared to the old one. Obviously, the txn is incomplete. The same thing happens when canceling without making a payment and coming back to the merchant site.

The above problem persists for both the payment gateways.

I tried many tips and tricks suggested by folks on this website and others and nothing seems to work.

Needs assistance pls.